# What can I do to use git properly in Terminal?

Tags: git, macos, github, terminal

*No matter what I try, I can't get it to work, i've been told to use*

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git config --global user.email you@example.com
git commit --amend --reset-author:
```

but I always end up in a place that I have no clue as to what I'm doing, or how to even get out of that setting safely.

the .git/ is in my memory_game folder, which holds my code for my project. The memory_game folder is held-- Let me just show you:

~/fundamentals/memory_game

Should the .git/ be in fundamentals instead of memory_game?

I feel like I may damage the system if I act to carelessly. Please help me out if you can, I'm just trying to learn. Thank you for your time!

Below is my most recent terminal activity:

> On branch master
>
> No commits yet
>
> Untracked files: (use “git add …” to include in what will be
>   committed)
>
> ```
> .DS_Store
> css/
> images/
> index.html
> js/ nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use “git add” to track)
> ```
>
> Your name and email address were configured automatically based on
>   your username and hostname. Please check that they are accurate. You
>   can suppress this message by setting them explicitly:
>
> ```
> git config --global user.name "Your Name"
> git config --global user.email you@example.com
> ```
>
> After doing this, you may fix the identity used for this commit with:
>
> ```
> git commit --amend --reset-author
> 11 files changed, 202 insertions(+)
> create mode 100644 .DS_Store
> create mode 100644 css/style.css
> create mode 100644 images/.DS_Store
> create mode 100644 images/back.png
> create mode 100644 images/king-of-diamonds.png
> create mode 100644 images/king-of-hearts.png
> create mode 100644 images/queen-of-diamonds.png
> create mode 100644 images/queen-of-hearts.png
> create mode 100644 index.html
> create mode 100644 js/main.js
> ```
>
> User-MBP:memory_game user$ git push origin master
>
> ```
> fatal: ‘origin’ does not appear to be a git repository
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
> ```
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.
>
> ```
>   Users-MBP:memory_game usernameishere$ git status
>   On branch master
>   nothing to commit, working tree clean
>   Users-MBP:~ username$ cd fundamentals
>   Users-MBP:fundamentals username$ cd memory_game
> ```
>
> Users-MBP:memory_game username$ ls -a
>
> ```
> . .DS_Store   css index.html
> … .git    images  js
> ```
>
> Users-MBP:memory_game username$ git init
>
> Reinitialized existing Git repository in 
>   /Users/username/fundamentals/memory_game/.git/
>
> Users-MBP:memory_game username$ git status
>
> On branch master nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: `origin` is unset as you haven't set any remotes. Where do you intend to `push` to? You need to set a remote for that.

Answer (score 1):

The `git config --global` commands simply set some global configuration, telling git who you are. (You need to do that only once. And you should of course use your real name and email.)

If the `.git` directory should live at `~/fundamentals/memory_game` or `~/fundamentals` depends on if you want to manage only your memory_game or all the fundamentals.

Typing `git push` will try to push your commits to some remote place. You never told git the location of that place. Therefore the error.

Those are really some very basic issues. You first need to understand the basic concepts. Please have a look at some introductions to git:

- https://try.github.io/
- https://git-scm.com/book/

Comment: Thank you very much, Michas! I'll use the resources you've provided for me. I appreciate your time.

Comment: Also look at https://think-like-a-git.net and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ffBJ4sVUb4

Answer (score -1):

Check the output of `git remote -v`. It shows the remote repository to which your local changes will be pushed when you run `git push origin master`. If you don't have origin set into remotes, you need to set it by `get remote add origin <link to your remote repository>`.